# Setting post excerpt length in php wordpress code, Should will help to save DB size?

Tags: excerpt

I am trying to optimize wordpress DB. As Google or any other search engine only reads around 300 char of data per blog, It's better to set excerpt length to 300 char. but doing this do we save DB memory?

Comment: Are you having a problem with database size? Is the cause of that problem long excerpts? If not, why is this something you’re concerned about? Also excerpts have nothing to do with Google, so that’s not really relevant.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes, trying to find ways to save database size.